# Check if date in an array is older than dates in another array

Tags: arrays, date

I'm trying to check the date from arrayA against the all the dates in arrayB, if the date from arrayA is older than any in arrayB then return.

Not too sure if I am able to check values in an array against other values in an array.

```
const dateA = arrayA.map((item) => {
  return item.date;

const dateB = arrayB.map((item) => {
  return item.date;

if (dateA >= dateB) {
return 'date is older'}
```

Dates in arrayA

```
[ 2022-02-21T05:00:00.000Z ]
```

Dates in arrayB

```
[
  2022-02-18T05:00:00.000Z,
  2022-02-10T05:00:00.000Z,
  2022-02-19T05:00:00.000Z
]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit confusing what you are asking, and there are contradictions in your question, so I'll make a few assumptions:

1. I assume that you actually want to know whether *all* dates in `arrayA` are **later (newer) or the same** - and not older - than *all* dates in `arrayB`. (I based this on the fact that you showed `>=` rather than `<` in your pseudocode and also showed an example in which this is the case.)
2. I assume that your arrays contain `Date` objects. (I based this on the array contents that look like they are copied from an `inspect`-like output - even though your pseudeocode looks as if there would be objects with a `date` property inside.)

If something isn't quite right about these assumptions, it should be easy to take the concept anyway and adjust it slightly to your actual needs. If for example you *do* want to make sure all dates in `arrayA` are actually *older*, then you'd just have to swap the two arrays in my examples (or invert all operations). Possibly you might want the condition at the end inverted - again I'm not quite sure what you really want because the question is very ambiguous.

---

So, for possible solutions: You *could* of course compare every date in `arrayA` with every date in `arrayB` (`if (arrayA.every(dateA => arrayB.every(dateB => dateA >= dateB)))`), but that would be unnecessarily inefficient because there would have to be `arrayA.length * arrayB.length` comparisons.

A more efficient option would be to calculate the oldest date in `arrayA` as well as the newest date in `arrayB` and then just compare those (which will result in approx. `arrayA.length + arrayB.length` comparisons - note the plus instead of times):

```js
const oldestDateValueA = Math.min(...arrayA.map(Number))
const newestDateValueB = Math.max(...arrayB.map(Number))
if (oldestDateValueA >= newestDateValueB) {
  console.log('Condition fulfilled!')
}
```

<sub>(We *could* optimize this even further by not using `Math.max` on the second array but instead `.every` for comparison with the oldest date of the first array, essentially a mix of the two ways, which would result in fewer comparisons in case a date earlier in the second array would already fail the comparison - however this makes it harder to read and understand in my opinion and the improvement is much less drastic than the previous one we did.)</sub>

Comment: Yes both assumptions are correct, I was using dumbie data to test out my logic, so that might have caused the confusion. The logic you provide is a more efficient way to handle this problem.